# I can't open my Pharmacy management software"based on sybase database"

Tags: odbc, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

I am stuck with my pharmacy management software running on Windows XP with a dongle as a security system. The database is Sybase.

I tried many backup copies but failed to open the program. Two windows appear: 
I am trying to find an online opener for DB files or any program that can do the job.I downloaded RazorSQL but couldn't deal with it as I am not advanced user, just newbie.How can I fix this issue and open the program or at least retrieve or extract data from [the backup][3] into `.txt` or `.csv` format?

I am the pharmacy owner, the management software is licenced, and the database is mine. There is no violation of privacy or intellectual property rights of any person. Nothing confidential to be hidden. I am simply sad that the system crashed, and for some reason I have to wait 3 days until I get technical support to get this issue fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) or anything that links in with it like [`DBD::Sybase`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MEWP/DBD-Sybase-1.16/Sybase.pm) to connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I thought that I can find an easy  online converter or opener. I am not qualified to deal with these indeph details as it is out the scope of my study. I was concerned with extracting some data out there and couldn't wait until I get technical support.

Comment: No way with a converter, you will need some professional with db knowledge for this